# How to get list of connected WebCams in avicap32.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, webcam

I'm coding an application to handle WebCams. I have to use (this is an external constraint) the avicap32.dll library. So here I am, using some extern functions (for which I have to marshal types) from this library, as well as user32 (sending WindowsMessages). And I digged up half the Internet, but failed to find how to get list of all the connected WebCam devices?

Of course I'm fully aware of function:

```
[DllImport(avicap32dll)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool capGetDriverDescription(
    short driverIndex,
    StringBuilder name, int nameSize,
    StringBuilder version, int versionSize);
```

, but it gives me list of **drivers**, not **cams**! When I connect two cameras to my PC, I still can find only one capture driver by this function (checking driverIndex from 0 to 9). Both of them must be using the same capture driver. So, not having a list of WebCams I cannot really decide, to which one I want to connect. There is a WindowsMessage WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOSOURCE, but it doesn't show video source dialog before I connect with a WebCam.

Comment: Use newer APIs, VFW is really old and not flexible at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm bound to avicap32.dll . It's for classes at college, and... you know. It just **must** be this dll. Why? Because.

Comment: That's all you have there. The API comes from time when video capture device was high end hardware. You can enumerate drivers 0 to 9 and there possibly is a response for specific index.

Comment: Yeah. I'm checking all of these 10 indices, finding only one driver, even if 2 cams in usbs. That's not good. Even though, could you point me to some specific API, that should work? I'm telling, that I already (though we can't...) change to WIA2, but our cams appeared to be incompatible with WIA2.

Comment: This is the newer API - [Finding Your Web Cam with C# & DirectShow.NET](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2012/01/finding-your-web-cam-with-c-directshow-net/)

Comment: Thanks! It's surely worth to look. Pity you've answered in comment, cause I can't mark question as answered, nor give you +1.

Comment: Use it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202464/How-to-use-a-WebCam-in-C-with-the-NET-Framework-4 or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control Both projects are based on MS Expression Encoder SDK. Install MS Expression Encoder 4 SP2 it has that SDK included. Simple to use and 100% compatibility with ANY WebCam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is legacy API (Video for Windows, avicap32.dll) and it is not that flexible as you could expect. Still being supported though.

Newer API with the best coverage is DirectShow, it is native, but with DirectShow.NET you have a bridge into .NET. Take a look at code sample and article inroducing this approach: [Finding Your Web Cam with C# & DirectShow.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20140716211944/http://www.barebonescoder.com/2012/01/finding-your-web-cam-with-c-directshow-net/)

**Edit:** Original article no longer exists, however found a copy in the Internet Archive https://archive.org/web/

Comment: Thank you. It helped me as well, I've been using avicap32.dll and it never really did what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Its easier and better to use the AForge.NET library. It contains all the tools to do these kind of jobs http://aforgenet.com/